# Google indexing for ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, google-index

I am running a website on an Ubuntu server with mongodb as database that is purely written in Nodejs. The app runs on a server and all the requested route to ejs files. Inside the entry ejs file of the site I used  tags with description about the site, however, still after a couple of days nothing from google is indexed. In generally, how should we let google index ejs pages particularly when there is not any html files.

Comment: Generally, Google takes a couple of days to index any site & I guess it has nothing to do with ejs or nodejs.

Comment: It could be like that but anyhow I wanted to get feedback from others about it. Thanks anyhow RopAli

Comment: Since nobody knows how google indexing algorithm works, all you'll get here is people's opinions. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not matter which view engine (razor, ejs, pug) you are using since all of them renders HTML as final result. So don't care about `ejs`. 
Google takes some time to index content. According to [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en) you can ask Google to (re)index.